# Having Multiple Image URL's Render Same Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create code that will allow me to use different image URL's but essentially render the same image.

For example, this would be across potentially thousands of pages:

```
<img src="https://www.website.com/image-path-unique-name-1.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.website.com/image-path-unique-name-2.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.website.com/image-path-unique-name-3.jpg" />
```

But instead of rendering a 404, an image would exist based on:

```
<img src="https://www.website.com/core-image.jpg" />
```

Is there some way I can do this? Either by systematically creating multiple copies of an image based on an initial image? Or maybe another solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can handle this via routing. I would say definitely don't create multiple copies of the image.

Comment: What would be relationship between the core-image.jpg and the rest? just some naming convention? something set on a database? your question is missing a lot of information, why would you have links to images that does not exist? what's the use case? where does "unique-name-X" come from? I guess you can have a route to match anything, parse that enything and return the image you want, you can even do that using the webserver like nginx with some pattern matching an rewrite rules, buy your question is too vague.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that you want some kind of "This image is missing" default image?